# Custom subject for New Order Email notification in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In WooCommerce I would like to set the product purchased in the "new order" email subject line, something like this: `New Order - [{product_name}] ({order_number}) - {order_date}`

I understand that `product_name` cant be used probably due to multiple products is there a way I can still do this by filtering product ordered or just allowing multiple products as not many multi orders go through.

I am very new to modifying theme code.

Answer (score 2):

The Email settings for "New Order" the subject need to be (as in your question):

`New Order - [{product_name}] ({order_number}) - {order_date}`

In the code below I replace `{product_name}` by the items product names *(separated by a dash)* as an order can have many items…

This custom function hooked in `woocommerce_email_subject_new_order` will  do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'customizing_new_order_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_new_order_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Email_New_Order object
    $email = WC()->mailer->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];
    // Get unformatted subject from settings
    $subject = $email->get_option( 'subject', $email->get_default_subject() );
    
    // Loop through order line items
    $product_names = array();
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
        $product_names[] = ￼$item->get_name(); // Set product names in an array
    
    // Set product names in a string with separators (when more than one item)
    $product_names = implode( ' - ', $product_names );
    
    // Replace "{product_name}" by the product name
    $subject = str_replace( '{product_name}', ￼$product_names, $subject );

    // format and return the custom formatted subject
    return $email->format_string( $subject );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

You will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: hmm trying the code now and I get an error. Thank you for the assistance provided already.



Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$item' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/*********/www/www/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/functions.php on line 23

Comment: You should always provide The woocommerce version you are using in your question … So what is on line 23? … Personally I have tested this code on WC 3.2.6 and it works perfectly.

Comment: WC 3.2.6 like you, thanks for the tip. Have not upgraded yet. The code on line 23 is........        

$product_names[] = ￼$item->get_name(); // Set product names in an array

Comment: @JamesPersson I have retested and it works perfectly well on my test server … I have added a screenshot of a new order email notification on an order with 2 different items that I have resent… It work as well as when there is only one item. My config is WC 3.2.6 | WP 4.9.4 | PHP 5.6.32 | MySQL 5.6.38 | Theme Storefront… Don't update WooCommerce yet as there is still some bugs and a lot of themes and plugins are not yet ready. WC version 3.3.1 is not yet good for production...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Is the above code is working for latest version of woocommerce

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - there is now a syntax error for WooCommerce 3.8.0 .  Wordpress does not recognize $item in this line -```$product_names[] = ￼$item->get_name();``` .
Do you know what the proper syntax should be?