# Change New Order email notification from name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Email notification of New order process has `'My Blog'` title.

I look into Woocommerce setting but could not find it.

Any Idea how to change `'My Blog'` to `'X Company'`
*red underline text in attached images.*

**Plateform: Wordpress + Woocommerce**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after digging, its very easy.

**WooCommerce>Setting>Emails**

At the bottom, there is section where you can header and footer text.
Simple.
Really appreciate your help @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

What you want to change is  the "From name" and it can be changed using:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_from_name', 'change_new_order_email_from_name', 10, 2 );
function change_new_order_email_from_name( $from_name, $email ){
    if( $email->id === 'new_order' )
        $from_name = __("ACME corp");

    return $from_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**Addition:** To add custom placeholders for the email subject *(for woocommerce 3.2+)*:

```
// Only for woocommerce versions 3.2 + (up to 3.2)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'custom_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = $email->object;

    // Additional wanted placeholders in the array of find / relace pairs
    $additional_placeholders = array(
        '{shop_company}' => __("ACME corp"),
    );

    // return the clean string with new replacements
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Then in your email settings, on the Subject field of an email notification you will be able to replace for example:
>
> ```
> Your {site_title} order receipt from {order_date}
> ```
>
> by
>
> ```
> Your {shop_company} order receipt from {order_date}
> ```

Comment: tested this method, and its change in the subject only but title is same as 'My Blog'

Comment: @faisal I have found what you are trying to change, so I have updated my answer and should solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this WooCommerce hook `woocommerce_email_subject_new_order` to change new order email title.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'customizing_new_order_subject', 10, 2 );
function customizing_new_order_subject( $formated_subject, $order ){
    // Get an instance of the WC_Email_New_Order object
    $email = WC()->mailer->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];
    // Get unformatted subject from settings
    $subject = $email->get_option( 'subject', $email->get_default_subject() );

    // Loop through order line items
    $product_names = array();
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item )
        $product_names[] = ￼$item->get_name(); // Set product names in an array

    // Set product names in a string with separators (when more than one item)
    $product_names = implode( ' - ', $product_names );

    // Replace "{product_name}" by the product name
    $subject = str_replace( '{product_name}', ￼$product_names, $subject );

    // format and return the custom formatted subject
    return $email->format_string( $subject );
}
```

For more details see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702040/custom-subject-for-new-order-email-notification-in-woocommmerce)

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
WooCommerce > Settings > Emails > Processing Orders.
```

Here you will find a field called `"Email Subject"`. Here, change `{site_title}` to whatever you want it to appear.

Alternatively, if you want to change the value of `{site_title}` itself, then head over to `Settings > General`.

Here you will find the field called Site Title. Change it to whatever you want it to appear.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Setting was fine, but for try I re-enter, but the result is same.